# Needs suggestions and help for my study

Tags: logistic, spss

My research question is 'to what extent does patient-provider trust impact African American males' compliance to prostate cancer screening recommendation? This is an exploratory study. I have no hypothesis. My goal is to see if there is association between trust in health care providers and compliance to prostate cancer screening using logistic regression.

The study is a cross-sectional design with a convenience sample of 67. I am using questionnaires a total of 19 to collect my data, one of them is a scale to assess trust while the other is to assess prostate cancer screening. I have problem with the screening questionnaire as it has multiple responses and i don't know how to code the responses into SPSS. This questionnaire is from national cancer institute' HINTS' STUDY so I cannot adjust the responses.

Here is an example:

Question: when did you have your most recent prostate specific antigen test? 
answer options:

```
1 = a year ago, 
2 = more than 1 but not more than 2 years ago, 
3 = more than 2 but not more than 5 years ago,
4 = over 5 years ago.
```

As for the trust scale, here is an example:

How often does your healthcare provider discuss options and choices with you before health care decisions are made?

Participants must answer questions with these response options:

```
 0 = none of the time, 
 1 = some of the time, 
 2 = occasionally, 
 3 = most of the time, 
 4 = all the time.
```

this scale consists of 6 questions.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to code these responses?
- How do I code these responses, especially the multiple response one into SPSS and how should I combine the scores of both questionnaires to run the analysis?
- Is the logistic regression appropriate to use?

Comment: You will have to see each question and code its responses in order of trust/compliance. Then you can run ordered regressions for each compliance question as outcome variable vs all trust question responses.

Comment: another meta-suggestion: choose a title for your post that is likely to let experts in your field determine quickly whether they may be able to help